# Tab does not tab and lets me out the code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, keyboard-shortcuts, github-copilot

I am working with `ipynb` file on Visual Studio Code. (with Github Copilot)

I thought it would provide **tab** or **Copilot autocomplete** when I press `Tab` key in a code block.

But it didn't, and let me out the code block - just like when I'm using `Tab` in a webpage.

I checked the **Keyboard Shortcuts** settings, but what I got were only the followings:

```
Emmet: Expand Abbreviation
accptSelectedSuggestion
editor.action.inlineSuggest.commit
insertBestCompletion
insertNextSuggestion
insertSnippet
jumpToNextSnippetPlaceholder
tab
```

I don't have any idea to fix this problem. How can I prevent `Tab` from popping me out of the codeblock?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

On the bottom right in the status bar it will say "Tab Moves Focus". Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd>.

Comment: Perfect. I appreciate you so much.